# How to convert big integers to smaller integers in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I have VHDL code where I'm trying to multiply pixel values. I have the following entity:

```
entity xGradient is

port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33 : in integer range 0 to 255;
    gradientInX : out integer range 0 to 255
);

end xGradient;
```

I do the following operation on these:

```
gradientInX <= x11 + 2*x21 + x31 - x13 - 2*x23 - x33;
```

The issue as you may notice is that the values obtained from the operation exceed the range of possible values my output integer can be. My simulation crashes when this happens. I don't know the right word for what I'm trying to do and therefore can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem and it's driving me crazy. I basically just want to truncate, or reduce the size of the output to ensure it fits into the gradientInX output port. I tried using a process block like this:

```
-- declared signals
signal gradientMem: integer;

--beginning of my architecture
begin 

SobelOperator : process(gradientMem)

begin
    gradientMem <= x11 + 2*x21 + x31 - x13 - 2*x23 - x33;

    if (gradientMem > 255) then
        gradientMem <= 255;
    elsif (gradientMem < 0) then
        gradientMem <= 0;
    end if;

end process SobelOperator;
```

then assigning gradientMem to gradientInX but it doesn't work for some reason. Any help would really be appreciated. Note: I haven't included all the VHDL code as I thought it would be unnecessarily long. The error message I get is that the signal resulting value from the operation is out of range (since the resulting value is negative and the output has a range of only 0 to 255).

Matthew

Comment: Your question misses two essential parts: 1) The declaration of `gradientMen` and 2) the error message. VHDL checks the range bounds on assignment. You want to create a saturation arithmetic. So define `gradientMem` with a bigger range.

Comment: I just edited it to include those. I guess my main issue was the sensitivity list not being correct. I was also wondering if VHDL has integer specific operations which force results into a certain range but I guess no such function or operation exists so I just have to implement it on my own. Either way it seems like my problem is resolved. Thanks for your response and feel free to add anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the few situations where you should use a variable instead of a signal.

```
SobelOperator : process(x11, x21, x31, x13, x23, x33)
    variable gradientMem : integer;
begin
    gradientMem := x11 + 2*x21 + x31 - x13 - 2*x23 - x33;

    if (gradientMem > 255) then
        gradientMem := 255;
    elsif (gradientMem < 0) then
        gradientMem := 0;
    end if;
    gradientInX <= gradientMem;
end process SobelOperator;
```

By the way, this operation is called **clipping**.

If you want to **truncate**, the process should be written like:

```
SobelOperator : process(x11, x21, x31, x13, x23, x33)
    variable gradientMem : integer;
begin
    gradientMem := x11 + 2*x21 + x31 - x13 - 2*x23 - x33;

    gradientInX <= gradientMem mod 256;
end process SobelOperator;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Paebbels suggests in the comment, most likely the range of gradientMem is not sufficient to handle the output of the operation.

Thing to note: in the integer operations, the intermediate range is (mostly) considered as 32b signed and the range is checked in the assignment. This gives quite a lot to speculate for the synthesis tool and can yield much larger design than optimal.

To overcome this, ieee.numeric_std.all is used for unsigned and signed types and operations. This gives absolute control for the intermediate vector lengths. This also forces you to gain understanding on what's going on in addition, subtraction, multiplication etc which typically helps in RTL design.

However, a thing to note is that in vector form, the operations are evaluated in pairs using the longest of the two as intermediate vector length.

For example:

```
  process
    variable i1      : integer range 0 to 15 := 15;
    variable i2      : integer range 0 to 15 := 9;
    variable i3      : integer range 0 to 15 := 11;
    variable i4      : integer range 0 to 31 := 2;
    variable iSum    : integer range 0 to 63;
    variable u1      : unsigned(3 downto 0) := to_unsigned(15,4);
    variable u2      : unsigned(3 downto 0) := to_unsigned(9,4);
    variable u3      : unsigned(3 downto 0) := to_unsigned(11,4);
    variable u4      : unsigned(5 downto 0) := to_unsigned(2,6);
    variable uSum    : unsigned(5 downto 0);
  begin
    iSum := i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
    uSum := u1 + u2 + u3 + u4;
    write(output, "int: " & to_string(iSum) & lf &
                  "us : " & to_string(to_integer(uSum)) & lf);
    wait;
  end process;
```

Gives:

> # int: 37 
>   # us : 5

Using parenthesis solves the problem:

```
uSum := (u1 + (u2 + (u3 + u4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

An error is in the sensitivity list of your process `SobelOperator : process(gradientMem)`. Here must be signals which influence to result signal(s) in other words this is a list of signals a process is sensitive to. So there should be `x11`, `x21`, `x31`, `x13`, `x23` and `x33` like `SobelOperator : process(x11, x21, x31, x13, x23, x33)`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Yeah I actually noticed that while writing out my question. I'll try to fix that and see what happens. I still want to know if there's a function in the numeric library for example that will truncate an integer signal from one range to a smaller one.

Comment: For the truncation of output you can use `std_logic_vector` type and take from bus just bit which you needs and then convert it to integer if you need output as `integer` type

Comment: Yes, the sensitivity list is wrong, but it's not the cause of his range problems...

Comment: @Paebbles I can't add comments because I haven't enough reputation, so I posted it as answer. Or what should I do?

Comment: Writing an answer is ok, but changing just the sensitivity list is not enough. It doesn't solve the out of bounds error.